Cannot get ethernet to reconnect after connection loss
I have a server that running Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS - I have upgraded between LTS releases a few times, and the server is probably a decade old. I'm not sure when it happened, but somewhere along the way, it stopped reconnecting after connection loss. I'm wondering if you fine people can give me a hand diagnosing it.
ip a lists a lot of devices, but the important two (I think) are br0 and enp1s0. The onboard nic stopped working years ago so I disabled it in the bios and switched to a PCI nic:
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)

Anyway, I can manufacture this problem by unplugging the Ethernet cable and plugging it back in, but when my ISP goes down, the same thing happens. Once the connection is lost, I can't get it back without rebooting.
I've tried the following on both enp1s0 and br0

sudo ip link set DEVICE down and then sudo ip link set DEVICE up
sudo networkctl down DEVICE and then sudo networkctl up DEVICE
sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd.service

But none of these commands seem to reestablish the connection. Anyone have any idea how I should start diagnosing this? I can repro on demand and get logs, etc.
When I pull the plug and then plug it back in I see:
Aug 07 07:45:40 *** systemd-networkd[930]: enp1s0: Lost carrier
Aug 07 07:45:41 *** systemd-networkd[930]: br0: Lost carrier
Aug 07 07:45:46 *** systemd-networkd[930]: enp1s0: Gained carrier
Aug 07 07:45:46 *** systemd-networkd[930]: br0: Gained carrier
Aug 07 07:45:48 *** systemd-networkd[930]: enp1s0: Lost carrier
Aug 07 07:45:49 *** systemd-networkd[930]: br0: Lost carrier
Aug 07 07:45:51 *** systemd-networkd[930]: enp1s0: Gained carrier
Aug 07 07:45:51 *** systemd-networkd[930]: br0: Gained carrier

To answer the questions in the comments, br0 is for docker/microk8s.  If I check dmesg after unplugging and plugging in (different day), I can see:
[Sat Aug 10 14:38:37 2024] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: Link is Down
[Sat Aug 10 14:38:37 2024] br0: port 1(enp1s0) entered disabled state
[Sat Aug 10 14:39:12 2024] r8169 0000:01:00.0 enp1s0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[Sat Aug 10 14:39:12 2024] br0: port 1(enp1s0) entered blocking state
[Sat Aug 10 14:39:12 2024] br0: port 1(enp1s0) entered forwarding state

And what is really confusing is I see a DHCP ack after plugging back in, assigning the correct IP. But, despite this, I can't ssh out/in and I can't ping the gateway.
My netplan is pretty basic:
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        enp1s0:
            dhcp4: false
    bridges:
        br0:
            macaddress: 2a:28:ab:aa:cc:68
            dhcp4: yes
            interfaces:
                - enp1s0

Thanks in advance,

Look at the network logs with the terminal command: sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager.  Also do: service NetworkManager status and service --status-all.

Thanks @waltinator - I'm on Ubuntu Server using netplan. AFAIK networkmanager is for desktop?

Have you tried renewing dhcp lease?

Why do you have a bridge? Is it for virtual machines or containers? What does brctl show? What does your netplan conf look like? Do you have a tcpdump? Does it show arp requests failing? Check the htop or ps auxwww processes, do you see nm or network manager. You may have it anyway. Does the disabled device show up in IP link? If you don't know, share the full list and state the model. Also look at dmesg for kernel messages

TY @sleepyhead - br0 is for docker/microk8s.
I've updated the original post to include my netplan and the results of my tcpdump, which incredibly, show a DHCP ack providing the right address from the expected DHCP server.... so weird.

I don't have the answer to your problem, but I have some insights into Linux networking. In short, your microk8s and the way it's manipulating the network is likely the source of your problems
https://microk8s.io/docs/configure-host-interfaces
Microk8s states, that by default the host interface is used. For you that is enp1s0, it doesn't state that bridge interfaces are used.
The only part in the documentation I see a bridge is for a CNI named Multus. Kubernetes normally does funky tricks with iptables to forward traffic and it does manage interface outside of netplan.
The command to show the interface connected to a bridge is
brctl show
it will show all the bridges, (for you br0) and the bridge-id (for me 8000.00e04c6823c7) and the interfaces (enp1s0 and vif11.0)
The command to show mac addresses on the bridge is shown with
brctl showmacs br0
The port on the bridge is the number in which brctl show is listed, starting with 1. The "is local?" means that the mac address is part of one of the interfaces that make up the bridge. When it's set to "no" the mac address has been learned through the port and therefor the interface of the bridge.
MAC addresses are mapped to IP addresses using the ARP table. arp -a will show you which IP addresses to MAC addresses are learned through the arp protocol (or neighbor detection in IPv6). If it's incomplete or stale, it has tried to find the ip address but not learned it.
For an ethernet bridge ebtables -L shows the L2 firewall, just like iptables -L shows the L3 IP firewall. The problem is that kubernetes plays with those.
There is also an rp_filter feature in Linux that can be enabled through sysctl
net.ipv4.conf.interface.rp_filter. That will prevent messages to be received from a different interface as than the routing table would expect the network to come from. This may not play nice with a bridge. I just don't know
sysctl -n net.ipv4.conf.br0.rp_filter
sysctl -n net.ipv4.conf.enp1s0.rp_filter
